# Combining mousemove and mouseaction script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a website with iframes and have a script that redirects to another site if the use does not use their mouse for a specific period of time. This timer resets on mouse action:

```js
function countdown(outputElement, seconds) {
    var s = 27,
        bs = 27;
    if (seconds) {
        s = bs = seconds;
    }

    function tF() {
        outputElement.innerHTML = s = bs;
        return setInterval(function () {
            s--;
            if (!s) {
                s = true;
                clearInterval(timer);
                window.open('http://example.com');
            }
            outputElement.innerHTML = s;
        }, 1000);
    }
    var timer = tF();
    onmousemove = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = tF();
    }
}
var old = onload;
onload = function () {
    if (old) old();
    countdown(document.getElementById('counter'));
}
```

However, I also have a script on mouse clicking, that is, each time the iframe is clicked it sends the user to the same page as the idle timer (in this case, it opens a new window http://example.com):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', clickeable);

function clickeable() {
    window.open('http://example.com');
    window.close();
}
```

In the case that the tab was opened via script, it closes itself, and directs to this new tab.

My issue is that I would like to combine these two actions but have had no luck since I'm all too new at this.
My requisites are:
 - The script runs a timer that resets each time the mouse moves, and in the case it reaches 0, it opens a new window, and ideally closes itself.
- In case the user CLICKS on the iframe, the action opens a new window and ideally closes itself, but it STOPS the timer from performing this same action.

I'm guessing this requires an IF and OR condition but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm stuck to the fact that my timer script AND my mouse script open new tabs with the same content.

This is a temporary link of my site in case it's useful to someone:

http://unnameable.world

Comment: Java !== JavaScript. The two are very different languages.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely both that users will up-vote your posts and that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages, some styles are more appropriate than others). But, *pick one* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project.

Comment: ok thank you, I'm learning